# How to do bigram tokenization for words which are not in the dictionary in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to do bigram tokenization using this code for words which are not in the dictionary.

```
if(match != j)
{
     matches <- (match != j)
     matches <- lapply(matches, function(w) {
     BigramTokenizer <- function(x) NGramTokenizer(x,Weka_control(min=2,max=2))
     k <- BigramTokenizer(w)
     return(k)
})
```

But I am getting a warning as below:

```
Warning message:
In if (match != j) { :the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Can anyone tell me how to modify this code at once?

Comment: It doesn't look like you need an explicit if statement here. Try instead, `lapply(match[match != j], function(w) {... `. And continue from there. That way, the if condition is implicit as the function will only apply to the subset you identified originally.

Comment: On trying the same, I am getting a warning message as:            [Warning message:
In matches != j :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length]

Comment: This is the problem with helping someone without seeing some of their data. I'm here guessing what's in your data. The solution hinges on how your data is structured. With that said, I think "not equal" `!=` is the wrong operator for this case. Try `match[!match %in% j]`. The best thing you can do is provide an example of what `match` looks like or `j`. That way there is no ambiguity with respect to the correct solution.